# Safari 6.0.4 refuses to use websocket with socket.io (error 9843

Tags: safari, websocket, socket.io

So Safari falls back to xhr-polling, since secure websocket connection fails with error "OSStatus error -9843"

I'm using Node 0.10.7, socket.io 0.9.14, Safari 6.0.4 Mac. My SSL cert is self-signed, local stuff.

This works fine in all other browsers and worked with older versions of Safari too.

Any ideas suggestion how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own q:)

So this was a SSL error, certificate was pointing to wrong subdomain.. Strangely HTTPS / SPDY still worked, only websockets failed.

After regenerating cert with OpenSSL everything is fine.

Btw 9843 means peer hostname mismatch. Just noted this since I wasn't able to find too many resources in Google.

A list of SSL error codes can be found here (check the enum):

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-36800/lib/SecureTransport.h

Comment: I'm getting -9807 error. HTTPS works but wss throws an error. How did you redo the cert to get wss included?